# Second largest value in a list that includes equal numbers

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
        A
1      20
2      15
3      20
4      18
5      14
```

As you can see the values can appear more than one time *(e.g. 20)* in the list. Therefore, I use the following formula to get the largest value:

```
={INDEX(A:A,MATCH(LARGE(A1:A99-ROWS(A1:A99)/9^9,ROWS(A1)),A1:A99-ROWS(A1:A99)/9^9;0))}
```

This formula works perfectly. However, what I want to achieve now is to filter the **SECOND** largets value out of the list with this formula *(in this case 18)*.

Do you have any idea what I need to change in the formula to get the second largest value from the list?

Comment: Do you mean the second **20** (`LARGE(A:A, 2)`) or **18** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LARGE` function can be overloaded to find the 2nd largest number.

I have to be honset that I don't understand why you wrote such a complicated formula to find the largest number, but, if you want to find the 2nd largest, 
try using `LARGE` like this:

```
=LARGE(A:A;COUNTIF(A:A;MAX(A:A))+1)
```

Comment: @ManishChristian Fixed the answer to prevent duplicates.